# JSP include tag dynamically

Tags: java, jsp, tags, taglib

I got many custom tags, which I will include in my page depending on a string.
I know I can make a choose/when list with each tag written out and switched by the given string, but it is not what I want.
Something like this:

```
<control:${controlName} param=${param} />
```

Comment: I guess that's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use some preprocessor, like frameworks such as Apache Struts do. In that case you'd probably have to implement your own markup and handle cases like EL that should be evaluated by the JSP engine, i.e. `${controlName}` would have to be changed in order to distinguish between your own markup and JSP/Java EL.

One preprocessor that you could use would be [Apache Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems to be too complicated.
For now I just create jspf files with the correct tag and already filled parameter.

Comment: @eeezyy if it works for you that way, that's totally ok. Dynamically generating code on multiple levels (e.g. Java -> JSP -> HTML) often is no trivial matter and in many cases might also get somewhat compicated, depending on your needs. If you can accomplish your goals with simpler means without sacrificing stability and security, then do it.